# Pack of 10 tickets in Metro, Paris, can you share?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, paris, ratp

I am reading about Paris and I saw that you can buy a pack of 10 tickets.

Are these only usable by one person, or they actually sell 10 separate tickets that you can share with others?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The carnet comes as 10 separate tickets and nothing stops you from sharing with others.

Comment: As a side note: If you buy the tickets at a railway station, they each are labelled with the price of the ticket. If you buy them at a metro/tram/bus stop, they don't have a price label. This may be important for someone, so I'm just sharing...

Answer (score 32):

Indeed you can. I'd extend this to other French cities as well: I have lived in [Lyon](http://www.tcl.fr/Tarifs/Tickets/Ticket-a-l-unite/Carnets-de-10-tickets2), [Clermont-Ferrand](http://nouveautes.t2c.fr/notre-gamme-de-tickets), [Mulhouse](http://www.solea.info/les-titres-de-transport-solea.html) and (currently) [Strasbourg](http://www.cts-strasbourg.eu/en/online-store/fares/tickets/), and in each of these cities public transportation tickets can be bought by 10 and shared.

Be sure to buy an actual pack (fr. *carnet*) of paper tickets if you plan to use them for several simultaneous passengers. If you buy electronic ticket batch (loaded on a contactless card) or a single multi-ride ticket, you won't be able to validate it several times in a row. This can be tricky to recognize, as some tickets will show you green light when validated several times, but only one ride will be deduced, and all passengers except one will be fined if controlled.

If you're traveling with family or friends, I advise you to check group ticket prices (usually called DUO, TRIO, FAMILLE etc.), they are often more advantageous than 10-ticket batches, provided that your group fulfills the requirements of the ticket.

Comment: Conversely, in Reims, a "10x1h" ticket is a single physical ticket. You can pass it to someone else for a subsequent trip, but you can't have several people use the same ticket on the same trip. This may be the case in other cities.

Comment: Also note that in Lyon and Clermont-Ferrand at least, this is only valid if you actually buy the paper tickets, of course. If you load them on the local card, it can only be used by one person at a time (and in some cases, only the named cardholder).

Comment: Both comments are very useful, thanks. I'll update my answer with this information if you don't mind.

Comment: This is highly misleading, it really depends city-to-city. For instance in Marseille (the 3rd largest French city), you get one large magnetic card that can't really be shared with others.

Comment: @yo' That's what the second paragraph of the post is about.

Comment: I can't help myself but the answer really looks like you have the option in every city, which is not true. In Marseille it's either a 10-journey pass, or 10 expensive individual tickets.

Comment: @yo' I am under the impression that this option is quite widespread, however, I only speak for the cities I have lived in. I also expect people to verify this information (that's what links are for), as in a couple of years some cities may stop selling such tickets.

Comment: "carnet" is also the word we use in English for this kind of multipack, actually in the French pronunciation style as well. For instance, http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=PAD&dest=BRI&grpo=1072&tkt=GWC

Answer (score 16):

**Yes!** They're not labelled, are separate, and work independently.

**Source**: Bought in bulk when in Paris with a large group. Worked out just fine. Also saved us money.

**Second source**: Some information about the tickets, prices and options:  [Paris by Train - Paris Metro Tickets](http://parisbytrain.com/paris-metro-tickets/).